# stuck on dynamic programming

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic

Heres the problem:
A Milkman serves milk in packaged bottles of varied sizes. The possible size of the bottles are {1, 5, 7 and 10} litres. He wants to supply desired quantity using as less bottles as possible irrespective of the size. Your objective is to help him find the minimum number of bottles required to supply the given demand of milk.

Input Format:

First line contains number of test cases N 
Next N lines, each contain a positive integer Li which corresponds to the demand of milk.

Output Format:

For each input Li, print the minimum number of bottles required to fulfill the demand

I have written this code for the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <tgmath.h>
using namespace std;
const int INF = 1000000000;
int m[4] = { 1, 5, 7, 10 };
int r[100000000];

int milk(int n) {
    int q;

    if (r[n] < INF)
        return r[n];

    if (n <= 0)
        q = 0;
    else {
        q = INF;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (n >= m[i])
                q = min(q, 1 + milk(n - m[i]));
        }
    }

    r[n] = q;

    return q;
}

int main() {
    int t, n;
    cin >> t;

    while (t--) {
        cin >> n;
        memset(r, INF, sizeof(r));
        cout << milk(n) << endl;
    }

    return` 0;
}
```

I have used dynamic programming for this.But I only get an output zero for every input.I am new to dp.Please help.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Thanxx for the help.Could you please tell me that whether I have implemented dp in a correct way.@NathanOliver

Comment: @TahaJiruwala It's up to you to find out, when stepping through your code using the debugger.

Comment: @TahaJiruwala It would also help you if you didn't name your variables with single letters.  Naming variables `r`, `t`, `n`, etc. conveys no information as to what they represent.  Also, is this one of those "online judge" contests?  I ask this, since you wrote that while loop in `main` -- why don't you hard-code the data that you're using instead of writing a loop that helps no one here.

Comment: you could shorten the list of `#includes`. As far as I see, most of them are unnecessary

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
int milk(int n) {
    int min;
    memset(r, 0, sizeof(r));
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        min = 10000000; // some very large value greater than n
        for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
            if (m[j] > i)
                continue;
            else if (r[i - m[j]] < min)
                min = r[i - m[j]];
        }
        r[i] = min;
    }
    return r[n];
}
```

I hope this works and it would help you , comment if you have any doubts.

Comment: Yes the codes working.Could you give a memoized version for this.

Comment: @TahaJiruwala Lol. Did you really just say that? SO is not a code-writing service. If you cheat at coding challenges, you're worse than Melania

Comment: @tobi303 .. Changes made by me .. Recursion could not solve large values , So , I tranformed the code to iterative one . (2)* . Error 2: Assigning const int INF a very large value and comparing with that value renders an error (Error suggestion: reduce that value), you can't store such large values and then do comparisons. BTW .. that was rude of you not looking at my code properly before commenting.

Comment: no it was not rude at all. Answers should answer the question and not simply consist of code only.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `memset` to set all elements of array `r` equal to `INF` – but it is storing `0` in all elements, because `memset` works with bytes and doesn't treat `INF` as an integer value. That's why you are getting `0` as the output.

Instead of using `memset`, you can change the code in the `while` block of the main function:

```
while (t--) {
    cin >> n;
    for ( int i=0; i<100000000; i++ ) r[i] = INF; 
    cout << milk(n) << endl;
}
```

Your code is working absolutely fine after making this small change.